# How to pass html id from react to html?

Tags: html, reactjs

I am having troubles passing the **id** of that **form button** (inside a react component) to my `main.html`.

```
<button id="path" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Calcule Path</button>
```

In my `main.html` i hope thit was recognized

```
var buttonRoute = document.querySelector('#path')
```

I have that the divs in orden

```
<body>
  <div id="form"></div>  
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  <p id="results">Resuls Tab</p>
  <div id="panel-de-direccion"></div>
  <div id="directions"></div>
</body>
```

So, right now i am calling to ReactDOM the **form** div (It works perfectly)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Form from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, 
document.getElementById('form'));
```

There is any way right to use **props**?

Comment: are you trying to execute `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector` right after `ReactDOM.render`. You might not get the result. You have to wait till the respective component is mounted to be able to query on the DOM to find that element.

Comment: Why would you do something like that? Why not manage everything with react?

Comment: I am using google maps api and his scripts just works in non-react html, i don´t want use react-google-maps